fetching and store function working time solution
now, I build a custom program on solana.
I have to make a custom program that can retrieve the Market ID of a user specified token and then also use that market ID to retrieve the Market Account, Event Queue, bid and asks slabs, requests queue, vault accounts for the token. Once retrieved it will store the information.
Then that information will be used to execute a swap thru Raydium v4.
that gets returned will be your market id if one exists for that token
let's say we create a function that obtains data corresponding to the market ID and stores it in the database when a specific token address is entered.
I want to make this operation time about ms. What method is needed?
what's solution?
either call gpa on the openbook program or gpa on the raydium amm program, and with openbook use filters: dataSize: 388, memcmp: offset: 53, bytes: basemint, and the pubkey that gets returned will be your market id if one exists for that token.
what's solution?
